# how to make transparent and floating Main Menu in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, interface

Does anybody know how to make interface like in the image below.

how to make transparent and floating Main Menu like in the image?

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 1):

You could design a layout for the bottom bar, make the background something like "#80000000" to make it semi-transparent, then use the [include](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) tag to display it on top of whatever other layout you've designed.

Comment: And for positioning, the RelativeLayout is well suited for overlapping widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two good examples:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

This could be done with [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in newer versions of Android so you have multiple screens with separate layouts and the menu that has separate fragment layout can be reused throughout.